# Deploying Power Platform Components on Different Subscriptions

Tags: azure, power-platform

I have several Power Platform components, such as a Power App and some Power Automate flows that are part of a larger application. This application also consists of a Python package, a SQL database and so on.

I am trying to deploy this application on a client's environment. Now, in terms of the Python package and SQL database, for instance, this would mean deploying it into their Azure subscription or tenant.

How would this work for the Power Platform components? How can I deploy it on their subscription?

Note: I am not sure if subscription is the correct term to use here. As far as I know, Power Platform is not a part of Azure, but it comes under an O365 or D365 subscription?

I know Power Apps and flows can be exported and imported into other environments/subscriptions. But, is there some way I can maybe set up a CI/CD solution in order to achieve this? Maybe using Azure DevOps?

I have come across this, but from what I understand, I believe this is about deploying these components in different environments within the same subscription?,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/azure-devops-continuous-integration-for-power-platform

Comment: if the python code (assuming is a secured azure function) and sql server use the azure AD to interact with Power Platform, you need to deploy azure to a subscription in the same tenant. One way to find is going to https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/ > admin centers > azure active directory. that will try to open the azure subscription for that power platform tenant

Comment: Perhaps it would be advisable to begin with making a manual "realase" to the client environments (maybe a seperate test environment on their tenant). And when you get that to work, then worry about automation with CI/DC, since this is another large topic.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Azure as part of you Power Platform solution, the right term is "tenant". 1 tenant can have multiple power platform environments and azure subscriptions.

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environments-overview#environment-scope
[image]

Devops for Power Platform is simpler. Best way to authenticate is using service principal:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tools#connection-to-environments

The Azure part is more complicated. if you want to fully automate you will need to write some infrastructure as code to create resources like an azure function or a database and after that the pipeline to deploy the code to those resources.